# Git - pull master and rebase into dev in one go

Tags: git

Suppose I am working on a dev branch of my project:

```
[16:08] ~/Dev/sandbox/repo $ git branch
* dev
  master
```

When I want to refresh my local view, the usual process is:

1. `git checkout master`
2. `git pull`
3. `git rebase [--interactive] master dev`

My question is simple: **Is there a way to succinctly do all 3 steps with one command?**

For bonus points, show me how to do it both with and without the `--interactive` flag in step 3.

Comment: Use a batch file (shell script)

Comment: `git fetch origin master && git rebase FETCH_HEAD dev`. Note that `master` is not updated.

Answer (score 0):

You'll never be able to do it in a *single* operation without writing some sort of simple wrapper script (because "pulling changes from a remote repository" is a fundamentally different operation than "rebase this branch").  However, you could simply write (assuming that you're on the `dev` branch):

```
git remote update; git rebase origin/master
```

This doesn't touch your local `master` branch.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks